# Validating XML against a Schema with Namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I have a couple of XML files that I have to validate against a Schema in my program. I have the Schema files stored locally and when I get the XML files, I know which schema to apply. I face a strange error when I tried to validate one of my XML file against a schema and this schema uses an import statement to import certain namespace. Here is a sample XSD that I want to be applied to my XML:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:test="http://www.test.com/test" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/test/folder/targetnamespace" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test/folder/targetnamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.test.com/test" schemaLocation="test.xsd"/>
    <element name="tag1">
        <complexType>
            <sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <choice>
                    ...
                    ...
                </choice>
                ...
                ...
                <element name="..." type="..." minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <complexType name="tag2">
        <sequence>
            <choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                ...
                ...
            </choice>
            <element ref="test:entries" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

The test.xsd is in the same location as this xsd file. The XML that I'm trying to validate against this schema is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag1 xmlns="http://www.test.com/test/folder/targetnamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/test">
    <id>ABCDEF</id> 
    <profile>
        ...
        ...
        <test:entries>
          ...
          ...
        </test:entries>
    </profile>
</tag1>
```

Any ideas as to what has gone wrong? Is the location to the schema file missing in the XML that I get? I want this XML to be validated against a Schema file that I load in my validation routine. Any thoughts?

Here is the imported Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test/folder/targetnamespace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/test">

    <complexType name="EntriesType">
        <sequence>
            ...
            ...
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="...">
        ...
        ...
    </complexType>
    <element name="entries" type="tns:EntriesType"></element>
</schema>
```

Comment: "I face a strange error" is a terrible problem description, because you then fail to tell us what that "strange error" is, and we can't see your screen from here. What is the **specific problem** that you're having?

Comment: Cannot resolve the name 'test:entries' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.

Comment: Please include your other schema (the one where the `entries` element is declared)

Comment: Added it as required.

Comment: You do not have an element named `entries` in your `test` schema (at least what you've posted of it here), so the error you're receiving is absolutely correct.

Comment: I added the element ref that was missing. But still I'm facing the same error!

Comment: It looks to me like the imported schema has the wrong target namespace (unless that's a copy/paste typo, but in what you've pasted the target namespace doesn't match the `xmlns:tns`)

Comment: That was not a typo error. I now modified my XML file to match the xmlns:tns namespace, but still I get that error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to get rid of this by loading both the XSD files in my validator routine. Even though one of the XSD file is imported into the other, it always kept failing even after correcting all the references to the namespaces. So I decided to load both the XSD files in my validator routine and it started to work since then.